# Couldn't find an AF_INET address for [hostname]

Tags: ros, multiple, machines

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when Running ROS across multiple machines ,it can share master for two machines,but when run a node ,it appear something like Couldn't find an AF_INET address for [hostname],I don't know why.
when I run a node in machine a,it pub a topic named "message",but I can't sub the "message" for a node from machine b,but when I use "rostopic list ",it has the topic named "message"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227410/couldn%27t-find-an-af_inet-address-for-%5Bhostname%5D/) by [cros](https://answers.ros.org/users/21043/cros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Searching for your error message finds a few other users who have had the same problem and resolved it. Have you tried any of their solutions:

- http://answers.ros.org/question/163556/how-to-solve-couldnt-find-an-af_inet-address-for-problem/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/206546/couldnt-find-an-af_inet-address-for-with-virtual-machine/

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0